# PHP error saying I cant upload image move_upload_file

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP website that sells cars. When a user wants to put his car for sale, he needs to add an image. When I try to do that, the following error occurs:
        Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:/xampp/htdocs/carMela/mainSite/assets/image/4-BMW-E90AC-Kit-by-Xclusive-Customz-Sheffield_16959173929_l.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\cars\class\userPost\userpost.php on line 165

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpCEDC.tmp' to 'C:/xampp/htdocs/carMela/mainSite/assets/image/4-BMW-E90AC-Kit-by-Xclusive-Customz-Sheffield_16959173929_l.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cars\class\userPost\userpost.php on line 165
>       Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.

And that line is:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['car_image']['tmp_name'], $target))
```

And this is my code for image upload:

```
/*this function for image uploaded */
public function save_image_info(){

    $image_extensions_allowed = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $file_name = $_FILES["car_image"]["name"];
    $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, "."), 1));
    $directory = $this->uploadFilePath.'mainSite/assets/image/';
    $target = $directory . basename( $file_name) ;
    $image_name     = basename($file_name);
    $new_img_url    = $image_name;
    $image_size = $_FILES['car_image']['size'];

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        if ($image_size > 5000000) {
            die('File size is too large! Please upload Small file.');
        } elseif(!in_array($ext, $image_extensions_allowed)) {
            die("You must upload a file with one of the following extensions: ".$ext);
        }
        else{
            //Now upload here
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['car_image']['tmp_name'], $target))
            {
                return $new_img_url;
            }
            else {
                die('Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.');
            }
        }
    } else {
        die('The file you Upload is not an image! Please upload a Valid Image.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My path to wasnt right,

```
$this->uploadFilePath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/cars/';
```

This was it so i changed and it worked, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your forward and backslashes, windows uses backslashes and you are using forward slashes which are used in linux, try to change them to "\" instead of "/". otherwise if thats not the answer then you will have to edit your question and show us your directory structure, the problem could be as simple as a spelling mistake

Comment: I did that and then second error occurs:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'car_image' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cars\class\userPost\userpost.php on line 155

What does that mean?

Also this is the code:

$image_size = $_FILES['car_image']['size'];

Comment: When Im uploading it says (C:/xampp/htdocs/carMela/mainSite/assets/image/, and my file folder isnt carMela its test, is that a problem? how can I fix that, this is a github code

Comment: it could be a file path problem